# Do blocks guarantee local variables will be modified in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

```
func foo() -> Bool {
    var apiResult : Bool = false
    myAPI.bar() { (result: Bool) -> Void in
        // some logic in block and local variable assignment
        apiResult = result
    }
    return apiResult
}
```

Is the value of `apiResult` guaranteed to be updated by the block passed in?
(I am a college student learning iOS, so please be as informative as possible)

Comment: If the block updates the variable then yes it will update the local variable.  Your function is always going to return false though because it returns before the block will run.

Comment: @dan The block may run before it returns..

Comment: You don't need the `()` with trailing closure syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a threading problem. A lot of times closures indicate some sort of logic that will be executed asynchronously. In your case you have an api closure, which I take to mean you're performing a network request of some kind. What this results in is the function `foo` starting, assigning `apiResult`, firing off the closure in line, then immediately return `apiResult`, which would be `false`.

A common thing you see with network calls is to have the calling function contain a closure in its declaration.

```
func foo(completion: Bool -> Void) {
    myAPI.bar() { (result: Bool) -> Void in
        // some logic in block and local variable assignment
        completion(result)
    }
}
```

When you call `foo()` it'll look like this:

```
    foo { (apiResult) in
        // apiResult will equal the result of your apiRequest
    }
```

One way you can return a result immediately is if you happen to have a caching system in place. You could pull from your cache and return that result if it exists. If it does not exist you move forward and run your async request. That sort of setup is generally seen more with databasing, however, image caching uses something almost identical to this. "I need photo xyz", check my cache to see if it already exists, if it does return that, if not, hit the network and return the value once completed.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the closure (block) to the `myAPI.bar` function. The function may or may not call the closure. If the closure is called then `apiResult` would change. The change may occur after the function `foo` returns though, depending on how `myAPI.bar` is implemented.

Comment: Would trying to update a variable that does not exist not crash the program?

Comment: In this case the variable will exist even after the `foo` returns. When you access a variable from outside its scope it is captured by the closure which means it'll always be accessible from the closure.

Comment: thanks @srvv but in the case that foo returns and the variable is deallocated from the stack, why doesn't the program crash? Does the compiler allow the assignment to fail?

Comment: The variable won't be deallocated since there's a reference to it.